# Python3 Virtual env unable to files that are saved in locations different from that of the virtualenv

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, virtualenv

I created a virtual environment for python3 in my home directory, I can run only those files that are saved in the home directory, if i try running a file stored at e.g., Desktop, it gives the following error:

```
(py3) gopi@gopi-inspiron:~/Desktop$ python detector_modulation_01.py
PyCBC.libutils: pkg-config call failed, setting NO_PKGCONFIG=1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gopi/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/compat/py3k.py", line 30, in <module>
    import pickle5 as pickle
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pickle5'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "detector_modulation_01.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/home/gopi/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/home/gopi/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "/home/gopi/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "/home/gopi/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 9, in <module>
    from numpy.compat._inspect import getargspec
  File "/home/gopi/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/compat/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import py3k
  File "/home/gopi/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/compat/py3k.py", line 32, in <module>
    import pickle
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 94, in <module>
    from org.python.core import PyStringMap
  File "/home/gopi/Desktop/org.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pycbc.waveform import get_td_waveform
  File "/home/gopi/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pycbc/__init__.py", line 135, in <module>
    import pycbc.fft.mkl
  File "/home/gopi/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pycbc/fft/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .parser_support import insert_fft_option_group, verify_fft_options, from_cli
  File "/home/gopi/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pycbc/fft/parser_support.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .backend_support import get_backend_modules, get_backend_names
  File "/home/gopi/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pycbc/fft/backend_support.py", line 77, in <module>
    mod = __import__('pycbc.fft.backend_' + scheme_name, fromlist = ['_alist', '_adict'])
  File "/home/gopi/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pycbc/fft/backend_cpu.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .core import _list_available
  File "/home/gopi/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pycbc/fft/core.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pycbc.types import Array as _Array
  File "/home/gopi/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pycbc/types/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .array import *
  File "/home/gopi/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pycbc/types/array.py", line 32, in <module>
    import h5py
  File "/home/gopi/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py", line 46, in <module>
    from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
  File "h5py/h5t.pxd", line 14, in init h5py._conv
  File "h5py/numpy.pxd", line 66, in init h5py.h5t
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'dtype'
```

Also I cannot import numpy or PyCBC at Python shell opened at Desktop. The main use of this virtualenv is to run PyCBC codes using Python3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because environments' root located at the directory you create it, so it's blind to directories that are of a higher hierarchy than it (e.g., if your `home` dir path is `C:\Username\Home` and you create a virtual environment in it - it won't be able to see files in `C:\Username` dir), that's one of the reasons you create a virtual environment in the first place, so that it won't conflict with files in other directories.

So to fix it you basically have two options:

1. Create an environment in the top-heirarchy directory of your files you plan to use.
2. Move your files to a directory that your current environments' root dir is a root of.

Cheers.